# Thymeleaf Could not bind form errors using expression "*"

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I use Spring-boot and Thymeleaf template engine and I try use `th:classappend` attribute for adding optional "has-error" class for < div > html tag using `#fields.hasErrors('*')` expression

```
<form method="POST" action="/registration" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create your account</h2>

        <div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('*')} ? 'has-error' : ''">
            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus="true"/>
            <p class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('*')} ? 'has-error' : ''">
            <input name="password" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autofocus="true"/>
            <p class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('*')} ? 'has-error' : ''">
            <input name="passwordConfirm" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm your password" autofocus="true"/>
            <p class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('passwordConfirm')}" th:errors="*{passwordConfirm}"></p>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>


    </form>
```

but I have this error

> Could not bind form errors using expression "*". Please check this
>   expression is being executed inside the adequate context (e.g. a
>    with a th:object attribute)

my controller methods

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String registration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());

        return "registration";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.save(userForm);

        securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

        return "redirect:/welcome";
    }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer is already in the error you get ` Please check this expression is being executed inside the adequate context (e.g. a with a th:object attribute)`. Your form element should contain a `th:object="${userForm}"` expression else it doesn't know which command object to use.

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add `th:object="${userForm}` attribute to my form element. And now it work fine!